# How to change properties of triggerBody in Azure logic app?

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which triggered by http requests.
And I got a request with body like this:

```
{
  "$content-type": "APPLICATION/XML; charset=ASCII",
  "$content": "PGE+sDwvYT4="
}
```

The content part is a string "<a>°</a>" encoding in iso-8859-1.

The char "°" get corrupted when I try to convert it into string using `string(triggerBody())`

But if the request body is

```
{
  "$content-type": "APPLICATION/XML; charset=iso-8859-1",
  "$content": "PGE+sDwvYT4="
}
```

`string(triggerBody())` will get a correct string of "<a>°</a>".

I'm not able to force every requests send with correct charset property, and I do not want to create an Azure function to convert encoding for this. Is there any chance I can use a logic app built-in function to get the request content encoding in iso-8859-1 instead of default UTF-8 ?

Comment: If you control the service that calls your endpoint, have you tried setting the content type in the header?

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for a third party connector, you get the best of both worlds re: code.  You don't need to spin up a function but you can use C# to achieve the outcome you're after.

With that, if (when returned to the LogicApps framework) it doesn't want to deal with that character, you could do extra processing within that operation to get the desired outcome.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/c-script-execute/

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

You can sign up for a free trial and it's quite affordable for what you get.

[image: Result]